# XSl -- need help with transformation

Tags: xslt, select, tags, repeat

I am new to XSLT and am trying to solve the following transformation.

I have an XML that looks like this...

```
<Groups>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>52</GroupSelector> 
  <GroupDescription>Group 52</GroupDescription> 
    <GroupValue>ABCD</GroupValue> 
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>27</GroupSelector> 
  <GroupDescription>Group 27</GroupDescription> 
  <GroupValue>PQRS</GroupValue> 
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>20</GroupSelector> 
  <GroupDescription>Group 20</GroupDescription> 
  <GroupValue>XYZA</GroupValue> 
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>15</GroupSelector> 
  <GroupDescription>Group 15</GroupDescription> 
  <GroupValue>MNOP</GroupValue> 
 </Group>
</Groups>
```

There may be 0 to n number of 'Group's

I am trying to apply an XSLT to find a 'Group' where 'GroupSelector' value is 20 and create output like this;

```
<GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="false">20</GroupSelection>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="false">Group 20</GroupSelection>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="false">XYZA</GroupSelection>
```

If none of the n 'Group's have a 'GroupSelector' with value 20, the output should be as such;

```
<GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="true"/>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="true"/>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="true"/>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Lola

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple, easy solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need parametric transform, two template with literal result elements (without AVT) is enough:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Group[GroupSelector=20]">
        <GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupSelector"/>
        </GroupSelection>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupDescription"/>
        </GroupSelection>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupValue"/>
        </GroupSelection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Group[
        not(following::Group)
        and not(preceding::Group[GroupSelector=20])
        and not(GroupSelector=20)]">
        <GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="true"/>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="true"/>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="true"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise, if the group selection is variable (you need parametric transform) you can accomodate the above solution with useful template mode pattern:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="selector" select="20"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Group">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[GroupSelector=$selector]" 
            mode="selection"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[
            not(following::Group)
            and not(preceding::Group[GroupSelector=$selector])
            and not(GroupSelector=$selector)]" 
            mode="noselection"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Group" mode="selection">
        <GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupSelector"/>
        </GroupSelection>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupDescription"/>
        </GroupSelection>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="GroupValue"/>
        </GroupSelection>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Group" mode="noselection">
        <GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="true"/>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="true"/>
        <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="true"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously, in XSLT 2.0 you can work with variable directly, and write something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/Group[GroupSelector=$selector]">
```

Thus making things simpler.

Comment: Why should anyone use such redundand code? Not only waste of space, but also problematic maintainability.

Comment: @Dimitre I didnt care here about reusability. About space, it's not used much space than in your template. I gain in readability.

Comment: You must be quite confused, @empo, to say you "gain readability" having a complex expression with different axes, 3 templates and two different modes, ..., and a lot of repeating/redundand code ...

Comment: @Dimitre Don't see where the complex expression is :P

Comment: It's quite obvious that you don't see this, @empo

Answer (score 1):

**This simple (short, only one template, no modes, no axes) and powerful (parameterized to work with any possible Group Id) transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pGroupId" select="'20'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
     "/*/Group[GroupSelector=$pGroupId]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup"
                     Missing="{not($vGroup)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup/GroupSelector"/>
     </GroupSelection>
     <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes"
                Missing="{not($vGroup)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup/GroupDescription"/>
     </GroupSelection>
     <GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal"
                     Missing="{not($vGroup)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup/GroupValue"/>
     </GroupSelection>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Groups>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>52</GroupSelector>
  <GroupDescription>Group 52</GroupDescription>
    <GroupValue>ABCD</GroupValue>
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>27</GroupSelector>
  <GroupDescription>Group 27</GroupDescription>
  <GroupValue>PQRS</GroupValue>
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>20</GroupSelector>
  <GroupDescription>Group 20</GroupDescription>
  <GroupValue>XYZA</GroupValue>
 </Group>
 <Group>
  <GroupSelector>15</GroupSelector>
  <GroupDescription>Group 15</GroupDescription>
  <GroupValue>MNOP</GroupValue>
 </Group>
</Groups>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="false">20</GroupSelection>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="false">Group 20</GroupSelection>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="false">XYZA</GroupSelection>
```

**If in the above document we change**:

```
  <GroupSelector>20</GroupSelector>
```

**to**:

```
  <GroupSelector>21</GroupSelector>
```

**and apply the same transformation on the modified XML document, again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<GroupSelection ElementName="FoundGroup" Missing="true"/>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupDes" Missing="true"/>
<GroupSelection ElementName="GroupVal" Missing="true"/>
```

**Explanation**: Use of:

1. **`<xsl:variable>`**
2. **AVT** (Attribute Value Templates).
3. **The XSLT processing model and built-in template for text nodes**.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it does not worth complicate an answer as such, just to make possible reusing a few literal elements.

Comment: Just a note, bad indentation here makes your answer heavy to understand.

Comment: @empo: Why do you think a solution which is twice shorter than yours is "complicated" ? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand the use of the strong. Also it's kinda disturbing :)